# When you specify more than one class, which gets used?

Tags: html, css

If you have an element with two classes assigned to it and the CSS for the two classes disagree on something, which gets used? And is there a way to control which one gets used?

For example:

```
<p class='red small'>Some Text Here</p>
```

with the CSS:

```
.red { color:#ff0000; font-size:200%; }
.small { font-size:50%; }
```

Clearly my text would come out red, but what size would it be? And is there a cross-browser way to control it?

Comment: It will be 50% at the end, as it was declared later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All classes you assign are used.

In case of conflicting property values, the priority is given to the [most specific one](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity) or if the specificities are the same, to the one that comes last.

So it's just like if you were using this class :

```
.redAndSmall {
    color:#ff0000;
    font-size:50%;
}
```

Most often a good design won't have the problem as your classes would have different meanings.

Answer (score 1):

`50%`, because it depends on the order of your css. The order within the `class` attribute is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

There is cascading used in css, firstly it will apply your inline styling if not found then the styling will be applied from head, if there is no styling found then from external file and if there is no external file then it will take the browser default styling properties.